# What's the short cut in Worklight Studio to open Xcode for iOS environments?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

In Worklight studio, we can select iOS environment like iPhone and then right-click to select Run As -> Xocde project, do you know what's the short cut for this action?

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Run As > Xcode project build option in Worklight Studio does not have a dedicated keyboard shortcut.

You can submit this as a feature request if you'd like: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/